# How to force restart of a dependent service in upstart?

Tags: 14.04, server, upstart

I have an upstart file for running a docker container:

```
description "Start a worker"
start on filesystem and started docker
stop on stopping docker
respawn

script
  /usr/bin/docker start -a my_worker
end script
```

When I restart docker:

```
initctl restart docker
```

The container service does not restart.

I tried to remove the dependency on filesystem:

```
start on started docker
```

And **it worked**, the container service got restarted after the restart of docker.

Is there a clean way to have this behaviour without sacrificing the depenency on filesystem, i.e. **can you restart a service, when only one of the dependent services is restarted**?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no, but if the dependent service has start on conditions that satisfy your dependency, then it would work. In this case, it seems like you should be fine.